# Android translateanimation of frame

Tags: android, animation

I have a problem with this instruction TranslateAnimation,
in practice when start the animation to move back of frame (from rigth to left animation), cut the frame on the right side,just the portion that is remaing out of screen when release touch screen...
instead when I run the animation for disappear the frame (from left side to right) .. example:

drag your finger on middle of the screen, finally release .. the animation begin and the frame disappears .. FAULT:
if I press it again on a screen in a point at random from the middle to the end of the screen the animation starts from the point where I pressed

my code:

```
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = null;
         int x;
         int offset;
       int tmp= 0;
        int avviato = 0;
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, android.view.MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.frame1);
            if(v == findViewById(R.id.frame1)){
            if(event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                    x= (int) event.getRawX();
    if (tmp==0){
            offset = x;
            tmp = 1;
    }

    if(offset < (x - WHIDTH /5) || offset > (x + WHIDTH /5) || avviato ==1)
    {
            params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int) (WHIDTH ), (int) (HEIGHT));
            params.leftMargin = x;
            params.topMargin = (int) (0);
            frame.setLayoutParams(params);
            avviato = 1;
    }

                    }//fine get action
            if(event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    tmp = 0;
                    avviato = 0;

                    x= (int) event.getRawX();
                    if(x > (WHIDTH /3))
                    {

                    Animation  animation= new TranslateAnimation(x - x, WHIDTH , 0, 0);
                    animation.setDuration(1000);
                    animation.setFillAfter(true);
                    frame.startAnimation(animation);


                    }
                    if(x < (larghezza /3))
                    {
                            Log.i("xxXxxanommmm", toString().valueOf(x));
                            Animation animation= new TranslateAnimation(x-x,0 -x, 0, 0);
                            animation.setDuration(1000);
                            animation.setFillAfter(true);
                            frame.startAnimation(animation);

                    }
            }
            return true;
            }//fine if v

            return false;
    }//fine touch
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly your screen is tracked with your finger sliding over the touch screen, but when you raise the finger from the screen, your layout "snaps" back to the left. Is that right?
For me this sounds like the standard Android behavior. I'm just guessing, but could you please check if your code is called anyway?

Comment: is not exactly.. when animation hasended if i touch screen again the animation restarts.. i would.. if animation hasended change focus on main layout.. but i try put a if(animation.hasended() == true) after declaration function traslateanimation the animation stop without any traslate.  at least that's what I think

Comment: Animation is asynchron, that means you cannot really check if an animation has ended, while your code is still running. What you can do to check that is to use the Listener `Animation.AnimationListener`and the `onAnimationEnd()` method.

Comment: so.. thanks for your help.. but not work D:, i put listener on activity and i have add set listener on animation, when animation finish i try frame.setClickable(false); but I cant press the keys that were under the frame

Comment: ok i have resolved a question.. with a resize of frame after the animation.. thanks a lot for your help, thanks again.